# php session variable value destroyed after reaload page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, session

I have a problem with sessions in wordpress. First I've activated the use of sessions in my functions.php and no I get the right variable but just after I reload my target site after setting the variable. When I load another page first and my target page seacondly my variable has a wrong value without any context to my first value. When I have the right value on my target site and I reload this site the value is also wrong. This is my code:

```html
//Activate sessions() in functions.php
add_action('init', function(){
      if(!session_id())
      {
          session_start();
      }
}, 1);

//Calculate the variable
$gesamtumsatz_kcal = round (($value1 + $value2 + $value3), 0); 

//Then set the session variable
$_SESSION['gesamtumsatz_kcal'] = $gesamtumsatz_kcal;

//Get my session variable on another page somewhere on my site
if(isset($_SESSION['gesamtumsatz_kcal'])) {
 $gesamtumsatz_kcal = $_SESSION['gesamtumsatz_kcal'];
} else {
 $gesamtumsatz_kcal = '';
}

//Echo my variable
echo $gesamtumsatz_kcal;
```

Do you have any idea whats wrong? I'm absolutely at the end with this....

Thanks a lot!

- - - - - - - - I have to add this

When I define a constant variable without calculate something like this:

```html
//Define the variable
$_SESSION['test'] = 1056;

//Get the variable
$test = $_SESSION['test'];
    
//Echo the variable
echo $test;
```

I always get the right value: 1056 back... What is this? Can't uderstand

Comment: No one has an answer? Thats so bad.... again

Comment: I have had that issue before and it was caused by a security plugin (iThemes Security I believe) that stripped the session cookie

Comment: @NicolasGaller oh that sounds crazy :o I use All In One WP Security, what was the solution?

Comment: I didn't find a direct solution, but I admit I did not research very long because I didn't want to change the security settings of the site (I was not the primary admin for it).  In my case I was developing a front-end web app for the site and so I was able to work around it by storing the settings I wanted to keep within javascript, but it is not an option in all cases...  if you have the same issue I had then you will be able to tell by looking at the response sent by the site in the Chrome dev tools and verifying that the session cookie (PHPSESSID) is not sent.

Answer (score 0):

wordpres destroys session when it is not opened. so use

`if(!session_id()) session_start();`

in the start of `wp-config.php` or better in the `init` of your code/plugin